# Webmail wicket widget to use in own application?

Tags: java, wicket, jakarta-mail, webmail, james

I need build in message functionality in my wicket application.
(send, receive, contacts list, attachments, reply, forward etc.)

For server side I try apache-james because it is written in Java - can manage all part of configuration from java code - create domains, accounts, change password, implement IMAP protocol etc. In apache-james contains Hupa subproject written in GWT.

In my application I can use Java Mail API or/and Apache Mailet API for access to IMAP server and write screens myself, but maybe somewhere exist something what help me ?

Answer (score 0):

What application server are you using?  Can we assume you are not using something like Apache Geronimo, Apache TomEE or other that includes a java mail component?

Comment: I'm using Weblogic 11 and Glasfish 3.1. My application connect via JavaMailAPI to James server witch is runing on seperate machine.